# Listbox item selection programmatically

Tags: xaml, listbox, uwp

I have an hamburger Menu with ListBox, When I click on items it is Highlighted and navigated to related page, but when I click on Any link inside the xaml page the hamburger item is not changing even the page is navigated. How to set Listbox item selected and highlighted from code behind.

I am calling the following function from wherever I need to change the Listbox item to my required one

```
public async static void ChangeSideBarItem()
{
    ADHome objADHome = new ADHome();
    string selected = App.SelectedPage;

    int x = objADHome.SideBarListBox.Items.IndexOf(selected);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(selected))
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < objADHome.SideBarListBox.Items.Count; index++)
        {
            HamburgerItemClass item = (HamburgerItemClass)objADHome.SideBarListBox.Items[index];

            string item1 = item.Title;
            if (selected == item1)
            {
                objADHome.SideBarListBox.SelectedItem = index;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the above method by setting the App.SelectedPage from different xaml page(orders Page) here i have a link Dashboard to navigate back to dashboard page, when i click on that the particular dashboard item in listbox(Sidebar) should be highlighted

```
private void DashboardLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.SelectedPage = "Dashboard";
    ADHome.ChangeSideBarItem();
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DashBoard));
}
```

But its not selected, when I debug it, shows null in selecteditem

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can just add your items to *ListBox.SelectedItems* collection:

```cs
private void SelectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // either by adding item from collection:
    myListBox.SelectedItems.Add(CollectionOfItems[1]);

    // or add from list itself:
    myListBox.SelectedItems.Add(myListBox.Items.Last());
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i did't understand ur answer

Comment: @Murali You asked 'How to set Listbox item selected and highlighted from code behind' - this is the answer to that question, you have your *ListBox* defined in xaml as `myListBox` with *ItemsSource* set as `CollectionOfItems`. I've just presented this as an event of dummy button click.

Comment: my collectionOfItems are binding to listbox and is working, but what i want is change the selected item without clicking the item in hamburger menu item(i.e listbox items). Ex : I have a Dashboard and Orders Item in menu, when i clicked on Dashboard, Dashboard.xaml is navigated to the frame,and the item is highlighted(by default style of Listbox) in hamburger menu, but when i have a link in Dashboard.xaml page like Goto OrdersPage,when i click on this  the OrdersPage.xaml is navigated to frame but the Hamburger menu still highlighting the Dashboard Item.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can override the `onNavigatedTo()` method and change the color of the item to the default. In the `(Frame).Navigate()` pass as argument to the other frame the `.SelectedItem` of the list to make the comparison.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

If we set the Collection to the `ItemSource` of the `ListBox`, we should be able to use the to set to the `ListBox.SelectedItem`. When my Collection is  `ObservableCollection<Menu> Menus`, we should be able to use the `Menu` object set to the `ListBox.SelectedItem`.

For example:

```
SideBarListBox.SelectedItem = Menus[1];
```

If we set the `ListBoxItem` by the following code, we should be able to use the `ListBoxItem` set to the `ListBox.SelectedItem`.

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox">
    <ListBox.Items>
        <ListBoxItem Name="FristItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock  FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="36" Text="&#xE170;"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Name="SecondItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock  FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="36" Text="&#xE171;"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

By the way, We should be able to use the `ListBox.SelectedIndex` to set the selected item.

When we set that the SelectedItem will be highlighted, if you want to change the other color to it, we should be able to use the [`ListBox.ContainerFromItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ContainerFromItem_System_Object_) to get the `ListBoxItem`. Then we can set the `Background` and the `Foreground`.